# How do I get current location by using Google Map or Apple Map

Tags: ios, gps, maps, google-maps

How do I get current location coordinate by using Google Map or Apple Map?

I want to copy and paste to email/whatsapp/waze.

I want some kind of this format. 3.1739161,101.984351

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

I've never understood why we couldn't get location coordinates from Apple Maps etc. Seems like such an obvious function.

However, you can use the default Compass app and it'll give you your current location at bottom of screen. See screenshot below for the format these appear in:

[image]

Otherwise you can also download dedicated GPS Location apps as well if you need different formats.

**[EDIT]**

Just thought I should add that tapping on the coordinates in the Compass app will then open the location in Apple Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can in Maps and Googlemaps.

You Can do it in [openmaps](https://appsto.re/gb/sfoCv.i)

In the app. Find your location then drop a pin onto it.

Tap the pin to get its pop up bar. And go to its info screen.

At the bottom you will see the coordinates. Press and hold on them to get the copy pop up. Copy.

Comment: openmaps the app really old.. should be iOS 6 apps, I can get the location, but I can't copy the value..

Comment: @Shiro Did you go to the infoscren/page?

Answer (score -1):

In apple or google map you can't... with google you can have it on desktop version